# Importing every line from xlsx in seed file - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby-on-rails-3.2, seed

On my seed I import some data from xlsx files. It's working for small ones, but it doesn't work for a particular file... This file has around 1265 rows and I have to run "rake db:seed" command 3 or 4 times to make sure every line is imported.

If not, it only imports some rows and then stops (without trowing any kind of error, at least that I can see...).

Here's my code:

```
# Insert Facilities
 puts "Importing Facilities..."
 spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new('app/assets/data/facilities.xlsx', nil, :ignore)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    facility = Facility.find_by_id(row['id']) || Facility.new
    facility.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
    facility.save!
  end
 puts "Facilities imported. "
```

How can I make sure that every line is imported? The line "2..spreadsheet.last_row" should do it but it doesn't work... Could it be a memory problem?

Thanks

Comment: When it stops, you have to modify the xlsx file and try again?

Comment: No, it just keeps reading for the rest of the rows..it adds a few more and stops again...

Comment: Is there any errors when it stop?

Comment: No, it finishes as everything was imported correctly... So I don't know if it's a kind of "time out" or "stack overflow" problem... :)